# Form tag screwing up page layout even with display: inline

Tags: html, css

In spite of reading no less than a dozen posts regarding this, I still can't seem to prevent this form tag from screwing up my page layout using every trick I can find.  I am clearly missing something.  The page validates with no issues, but this form tag is pushing my navigation bar down.

Here is the form:

```
<div class="skyblock2">
      <div class="form">
            <h1 class="white">If you have questions, we will answer all of them. <br />
            Leave your phone number and we will call you in 1 minute</h1>

      <form name="call-form" method="post" id="call-form" action="mysqlit.php" style="display: inline; padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: transparent;">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Your Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Name';}" />
        <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="Phone Number" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Phone Number';}" />
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('call-form').submit();" class="sky2">Give me a call</a>
      </form>

      </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
div.skyblock2 {
width : 100%;
margin : 0 auto;
background-color : #0093cb;
color : white;
text-align : center;
}
div.form {
padding : 25px 0;
width : 80%;
margin : 0 auto;
text-align : center;
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting; this only happens in Chrome.  Works fine in all other browsers.

Comment: Its a DOM issue you're using `display: inline-block` along with `float` and it will break one day or another.

Assign `.logo` and `.textlogo` to `float: left` and you're good to go for all browsers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

CSS

```
.nav { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
.top { position: relative; }
```